# How to sum up $\binom{47} 4 \binom41 \binom{4-1}3 +\cdots+\binom{47}{47}\binom{47}1\binom{46}3$

Tags: summation, binomial-coefficients, binomial-theorem

I have a question on Binomial theorem that goes like as the following:

Math 240 professors McBrain and DeCerveau are looking for problems for the weekly quiz. They found all four problems yesterday in their Combinatorial Grimoire, which contains 47 problems, but they can't remember which ones. McBrain chose the highest-numbered problem. DeCerveau picked the remaining problems. They discuss the number of possibilities: they agree if McBrain chose problem j for some $j\in[47]$ then DeCerveau had $\binom{j-1}3$ ways to complete the quiz. How many possibilities for the quiz are there?

Since we need to choose at least 3 questions out $j-1$, j is at least 4. I have come up with a general formula $\binom{47}j \binom j 1 \binom{j-1}3$ to say that there are $\binom{47}j$ to choose a $j$-elements subsets out [47], and we have for each subset $\binom j 1 \binom{j-1}3$ ways to choose 4 quiz questions.

I have tried to sum up all the possibilities as $$\binom{47}4 \binom 4 1 \binom{4-1}3 + \binom{47}5 \binom 5 1 \binom{5-1}3 + \cdots+\binom{47}{47} \binom{47}1 \binom{46}3,$$ but I am not able to come up with a concrete number as the total sum of possibilities.

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Seems like you want to instead evaluate $\sum_{j=4}^{47} \binom{j-1}{3}$.

Comment: @RobPratt Thank you for your reply. Could you explain why we don't need to first choose $j$ out of 47?

Comment: The value of $j$ makes this choice from among $\{4,\dots,47\}$.

Comment: You only need to count each $4$-subset once. But with your product of three binomials, you are counting each $4$-subset $m$ times, where $m$ is the number of $j$-subsets containing a given $4$-subset. That is way overcounting!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The desired sum is $\sum_{j=4}^{47} \binom{j-1}{3}$, which, by the [hockey-stick identity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hockey-stick_identity), is $\binom{47}{4}=178365$.  This count is expected because you know they chose $4$ questions out of $47$.

Comment: I see it now. We don't need to choose j out of 47 every time we choose 3 out of j-1. Thank you!